# Can I load a partial table from HDFS into PIG?

Tags: load, apache-pig, hdfs

For example: My tab separated table in HDFS has the following fields: Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4. I want to load Col1 and Col2 only in PIG. The following LOAD statement is not working:

LOAD '/usr/table1' USING PigStorage ('\t') as 
(Col1:chararray,
Col2:chararray);

Comment: Your method should work just fine.  What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: I agree with Winnie .. This should definitely work ..
Can you let us know whats the error ?

Answer (score 3):

One solution is you can write those two columns data to a new file and load the data into Pig.

Here you can use some AWK commands to that.

```
Hadoop fs -cat /usr/table1 |awk -f "\t" {print $1,$2} >>newfile.tsv
```

second solution is load 4 columns data generate only 2 columns data and use them.

```
A = LOAD '/usr/table1' USING PigStorage ('\t') as (Col1:chararray, Col2:chararray,Col3:chararray, Col4:chararray);

B = foreach A generate col1,col2 ;

store b into '/path/to/hdfs';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just load the two fields but you don't have to name all the fields
i.e.

```
A = LOAD '/usr/table1' USING PigStorage ('\t');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 as col1, $1 as col2;
```

When you do the generate early the further steps in the map/reduce(s) generated by pig will not incur the costs of moving the additional columns
Also assuming the file is big, I wouldn't use the cat and awk option suggested since this would not be as efficient as using pig (if the file is small than the map/reduce in general would be inefficient)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to move the table file into local directory and then you can use it in pig script

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /usr/table1 $HOME/tables/
```

and run this below code in grunt shell

```
A=LOAD '$HOME/tables/table1' using PigStorage('\t') as (Col1:chararray,  Col2:chararray,Col3:chararray, Col4:chararray);
B= foreach A generate $0 as col1,$1 as col2;
Dump B;
```